# systemd not restarting my process

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, arm

I have the following service configured:

```
[Unit]
Description=HB service started

[Service]
Restart=always # or always, on-abort, etc
RestartSec=3
WorkingDirectory=/home/debian/hb/program
ExecStart=/home/debian/hb/program/program1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I do:

```
ps -ef|grep program1
```

to get the process id and kill it with "kill". -- just to see if it restarts just as I had it written.

Thing is, the service is NOT restarting!! No matter what I do, whenever I kill the process, the service won't restart. Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: Do you see anything getting logged when the process dies?  Do you see anything in the status (`systemctl status`)?

Comment: not really. Well only this:   Process: 990 ExecStart=/home/debian/hb/program/program1 (code=killed, signal=TERM
)
 Main PID: 990 (code=killed, signal=TERM)

Comment: Did you run `systemctl daemon-reload` after making changes to this file?

Comment: Yes I did.... Well I think I fixed it though... I just switch the order of the things, moved up Execstart and moved down Restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out. This solved my issue:

```
[Unit]
Description=HB service started

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/debian/hb/program
ExecStart=/home/debian/hb/program/program1
Restart=always # or always, on-abort, etc
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Basically I changed the order of the things, and it worked... Weird but that did the trick.

Comment: And then people ask why I drink my bathwater when it gets to systemd... have oom-killer events that I wanted it to restart things... but it didn't, will be checking order now ;(