# systemd not restarting a process that depends on another process being up

Tags: systemd

I tried the fix here: [systemd not restarting my process](https://serverfault.com/questions/918392/systemd-not-restarting-my-process) and that didn't work for me.

I have a Kafka exporter for Prometheus.  I have Kafka running on the same computer.  When I stop Kafka, the Kakfa exporter dies (it depends on being able to communicate with the Kafka processes).  I would like the exporter to automatically restart after Kafka is started again, but this isn't working.

Here's my systemd file, below.  I've tried various things here.  What can I do to ensure the Kafka exporter starts after Kafka is finally restarted / brought back up?

```
[Unit]
Requires=kafka.service
After=kafka.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=kafka
# give kafka time to start up first
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 15
ExecStart=/opt/kafka_exporter/kafka_exporter --kafka.server=localhost:9092
Restart=always
RestartSec=30
StartLimitInterval=0s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try PartOf? From manual:

```
PartOf= Configures dependencies similar to Requires=, but limited to stopping and restarting of units. When systemd stops or restarts the units listed here, the action is propagated to this unit. Note that this is a one-way dependency — changes to this unit do not affect the listed units.
```

In that case unit should be like below.

```
[Unit]
After=kafka.service
Requires=kafka.service
PartOf=kafka.service
```

Comment: Tried this out (only modified the Unit section) and sadly it does not work.